# Functions in F# Discriminated Unions

Tags: haskell, f#

Is there a way to use functions in Discriminated Unions?  I am looking to do something like this:

`Type Test<'a> = Test of 'a-> bool`

I know this is possible in Haskell using newtype and I was wondering what the equivalent in F# would be.

Thanks.

Comment: The confusion is just that F# requires superfluous parentheses around the `'a -> bool` function type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As an expansion on desco's answer you can apply the function tucked into Test with pattern matching:

```
type Test<'a> = Test of ('a -> bool)

// let applyTest T x = match T with Test(f) -> f x
// better: (as per kvb's comment) pattern match the function argument
let applyTest (Test f) x = f x
```

Example:

```
// A Test<string>
let upperCaseTest = Test (fun (s:string) -> s.ToUpper() = s)

// A Test<int>
let primeTest =
    Test (fun n ->
        let upper = int (sqrt (float n))
        n > 1 && (n = 2 || [2..upper] |> List.forall (fun d -> n%d <> 0)) 
    )
```

In FSI:

```
> applyTest upperCaseTest "PIGSMIGHTFLY";;
val it : bool = true
> applyTest upperCaseTest "PIGSMIgHTFLY";;
val it : bool = false
> [1..30] |> List.filter (applyTest primeTest);;
val it : int list = [2; 3; 5; 7; 11; 13; 17; 19; 23; 29]
```

Comment: Note that since there's only one case in the discriminated union you can safely pattern match on the left hand side of `applyTest` so that you don't have the meaningless identifier `T` cluttering things up:  `let applyTest (Test f) x = f x`.

Comment: @kvb: nice! I forgot that function arguments are patterns too. I updated my post.

Answer (score 5):

```
type Test<'A> = Test of ('A -> bool)
```

Comment: Quick question.  How do you actually apply the function from such a binding?

Comment: Rip the function back out with something like `let (Test f) = Test(fun _ -> true)` to bind it to `f`.